# How to add Youtube Video Like in iOS app

Tags: ios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have requirement in one of my iPhone app.

I want to add "**LIKE**" and "**SUBSCRIBE**" functionality for YouTube video which is playing in my app.

I have static video youtube list which is playing in my app. Below this video, I need to add "**LIKE**" and "**SUBSCRIBE**" `UIButton`.

Can anyone let me know, how to implement "LIKE" and "SUBSCRIBE" function from iPhone app.

I have checked with below youtube apis urls:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

But I don't know what to pass in "onBehalfOfContentOwner" parameter, and what can be steps to achieve it from iPhone application.

Can anyone know about this how to do this from native iPhone app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YouTube Direct Lite for iOS](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS) has similar samples, you can pass "onBehalfOfContentOwner" as an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionTask;


    NSString *strToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",setTokenhere];
    NSString * strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?&id=%@&rating=like",setVideoId];
   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
   AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
   [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [requestSerializer setValue: strToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
   manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
   manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

   __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
   self.sessionTask = [manager POST:strUrl parameters:self.parameter progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
    {
          NSLog(@"responseObject -> %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
          weakSelf.sessionTask = nil;
          NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
```

> This code For Like the Video